# What is the problem of matching SIFT descriptor by using Euclidean distance?

Tags: computer-vision, matching, sift, euclidean-distance, feature-descriptor

I got this question but I didn't got any clue about the answer: What is the problem of matching SIFT descriptor by using Euclidean distance? I have read something about this method doesn't work with transformed images, but I could understand what he means about transformed image and why?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question when I started out in Machine Learning. Normally, SIFT features are matched by knnMatching which in default uses L1 Distance.

Let's begin by defining the equation of L1 and L2. Suppose you have (a, b) and (c, d),

L1 distance (Manhattan Distance) = |a-c| + |b-d|

L2 distance (Euclidean Distance) = Square_root[(a-c)2 + (b-d)2]

Here you can see that error rate in L2 distance increases rapidly as you have more dimensions due to square functions. SIFT feature is a multidimensional vector and Euclidean distance will increase rapidly compared to L1 distance which takes absolute value.

Euclidean distance is a good measure for vectors with lesser dimensions where as L1 distance is a better choice for vectors with larger dimensions.

Hope this clears your doubt.

Comment: Did you mean `L1` distance is a better choice for vectors with larger dimensions?

Comment: Yes. If you are comparing two feature vectors, in this case, SIFT features, it's better to use L1 distance since the error doesn't grow as rapidly as L2. Of course, there are other metrics too. I took an example of L1 and L2 since user was interested in knowing drawbacks of Euclidean. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Well, I agree with you. I wanted to point out that you have a typo in your answer where you say `L2 is a better choice with larger dimensions`

Comment: Corrected it. Thank you.